# Terminating QProcess doesn't kill child process

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following Problem:
I have a Qt GUI-Application (c++) which starts an external java application via a bash-script. When I terminate my QProcess the script is killed, but the child-process (the java-application) is still running.

I don't understand this behavior, because if I run the script in terminal and kill it, the child process is also killed. Maybe it has something to do with the various event loops in Qt, which I have not understood yet.

---

Here is my code:

MainWindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~MainWindow();

private slots:
  void slot_startQProcess();
  void slot_killQProcess();

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;

  QProcess myProcess;
};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  connect(ui->pb_start, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::slot_startQProcess);
  connect(ui->pb_kill, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::slot_killQProcess);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::slot_startQProcess()
{
  myProcess.setWorkingDirectory("./i2exrep");
  myProcess.start("./myScript.sh");
}

void MainWindow::slot_killQProcess()
{
  myProcess.close();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

myScript.sh

```
#!/bin/csh
java -jar i2exrep.jar
```

Folder structure:

- .pro File
- *.cpp
- *.h
- i2exrep (Folder)

  - myScript.sh

---

So my application starts "myScript.sh" which starts "java -jar i2exrep.jar"

Killing the QProcess only terminates "myScript.sh", but "java -jar i2exrep.jar" is still running.
   - i2exrep.jar

---

EDIT:

I tried the same with another main function:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QProcess myProcess;
  myProcess.setWorkingDirectory("./i2exrep");
  myProcess.start("./myScript.sh");
  return a.exec();
}
```

When I quit this program, then the Java application is also terminated. When I finish the first program (the GUI application), then only the script is terminated and the Java application continues to run. I get the following error message:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("./myScript.sh") is still running.
```

Comment: Have you tried using `QProcess::kill` or `QProcess::terminate` before closing? (You must wait a little after sending those before actually quitting. Use `QProcess::waitForFinished` to do so)

Comment: My guess is that myScript.sh is launching i2exrep.jar dettached, therefore it can run after the spawning process terminates.

Comment: @Felix: I edited the slot as follows: `void MainWindow::slot_killQProcess()
{
  myProcess.kill();
  myProcess.terminate();
  myProcess.waitForFinished(1000);
  myProcess.close();
}` Calling the method still stops only the script. The java application is still runing.

Comment: @Mike That's my guess too. But how can I prevent the Java application from running dettached? I would like to "link" the Java application to the parent process _myScript.sh_.

Comment: you `kill` (SIGKILL) the process directly, so `terminate` (SIGTERM) and `close` 
 (closing in/out streams) have no effect. You should only `terminate` it

Answer (score 1):

I assume you run some UNIX system (since the shell and `/` path separator).

Do you really need both processes (the shell and java)? Maybe leaving only java will solve your problem. Add `exec` to your script:

```
#!/bin/csh
exec java -jar i2exrep.jar
```

My guess is that when you run your application in a terminal and then close it, all child processes receive SIGHUP since they lose the controlling terminal. When you run the script from GUI application there is no controlling terminal at the first place, so java won't terminate on quit. Anyway, the correct way to terminate a child process is to send it a signal (SIGTERM, maybe SIGKILL after some time) and then wait(2) it's termination.

If you don't want to get rid from a shell process in your process chain, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146770/100274) to find out how to forward signals to child process in shell.

Comment: Yes, I run a UNIX system. Sorry, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: The only reason I use the script is that I do not want to call my QProcess like this: `myProcess.start("java", "-jar i2exrep.jar")` I start several other applications using QProcess, which is why I find the program name "java" somewhat inappropriate for this one application.

Comment: Well it's ok to run java via a wrapper script, but IMO it's better to avoid unnecessary "proxy" child of your application (which is /bin/csh). You can just prepend "exec" to the line in your script, after that killing your child process will kill java, not the "proxy" shell. This is because "exec" substitutes the address space of the running process (shell) with the code and data of the program being executed, and the PID of the child remains the same (i.e. only one `fork` happens).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `setsid` to start the process.

Please, check the example below:

```
process->start("setsid ./example.sh");
(...)
QString killingProcess = "kill -TERM -" + QString::number(process->pid());
system(killingProcess.toStdString().c_str());
```

For more details, please, visit [this](https://www.webhostinghero.com/blog/how-to-create-a-process-group-in-linux/) link.